# Computing number of subgraphs of directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Consider an acyclic directed graph (with no multiple edges) with vertices labeled as 1,...,N. We can remove any vertex for which there is no edge pointing to it. This operation can be applied any number of times from 0 to N. How to compute the number of graphs that we can get by applying this operation any number of times? We consider graphs distinct if the sets of their vertices differ.

The maximum length of a path is 5, the maximum number of vertices is 300.
Would be grateful for any hint.

Comment: I think this needs a little more clarification. I can think of several ways to interpret this. In particular, are you trying to count the ways you can apply n of these operations (where 0<=n<=N) to arrive at a distinct result, or are you trying to count the remaining subgraphs after the operations are complete?

Comment: @BrendanMitchell: we count every unique graph that can be obtained after applying the operation n times for any fixed n. Thus we count original graph, the graphs after applying operation only one time, the graphs after applying it 2 times and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). You will always process vertices in that order.

When counting a graph, the first step is to determine if it has more than one connected component. If it does, you count each component separately, then multiply the answers together.

Once you know that you're counting a single connected component, the answer is the number of subgraphs without that vertex, and the number with that vertex.

The number without that vertex is just a recursive call of the graph minus that vertex.

The number with that vertex is how many graphs of that form contain that vertex and all vertices dependent on that vertex. Which turns out to be the same as answering the original question after removing that vertex and all vertices dependent on it. (Note, this operation is likely to create disconnected graphs.)

And now there is one important implementation detail. If you add a caching layer, you are likely to find many recursive calls wind up with the same subgraph. And so cache the value and return that. This is called [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

---

After further thought, I realized that there is no need to do it in that order. If we take a random vertex in the middle, those without that vertex are those missing that vertex, and every vertex it depends on.

Those with that vertex have that vertex, and every vertex that it depends on. But that is in a one to one correspondence to first removing that vertex and all that depend on it, then doing the same construction.

So instead of doing a topological sort, we can shuffle the vertices. But we still want to always process them in the same order. With the hope that we'll be disconnecting lots of small graphs, and the same small graphs will show up over and over again in lots of ways, letting our caching layer work out.

Comment: Thank you for good solution and detailed explanation.